# Converter número natural em binário de forma recursiva

Tags: c++, recursão

Como eu posso transformar essa função em uma função recursiva? Eu consegui fazer ela iterativa desta forma:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int n,pot,bin;

    cout << endl << "  Digite o Numero: ";
    cin >> n;
    pot = 1;
    bin = 0;
    while (n > 0){
        bin += (n % 2)* pot;
        pot *= 10;
        n = n/2;
    }
    cout << "  " << "Result: " << bin;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o intuito for apenas fazer o *display* de cada dígito pode usar isto:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void ConvertToBinary(int n);
int main() {
    ConvertToBinary(11);
    return 0;
}
void ConvertToBinary(int n)
{
    if (n / 2 != 0) {
        ConvertToBinary(n / 2);
    }
    printf("%d", n % 2);
}
```

Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/sAUA0f).
Adaptado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26520065/2556111).

Comment: sei que isso é uma pergunta fora do escopo, mas porque você declarou a função acima do `main()` e só escreveu ela abaixo ? tem aumento de performance ou legibilidade de codigo ? ou e só questão de gosto ?

Comment: Já há muito que não programava em c++. O código deu erro ao compilar. Optei por declarar a função em vez de a passar para cima de main, por nenhuma razão em especial, foi o que me ocorreu no momento.

Answer (score 4):

Você deve definir um limite para a função. Neste caso o limite é quando o número a ser dividido por zero ou menos. Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
int funcao(int n, int pot, int bin) {
  bin += (n % 2)* pot;
  n = n/2;
  pot = pot *10;
  if (n <= 0) {
    return bin;
  }
  bin = funcao(n, pot, bin);
}

int main() {
  int n,pot,bin;

  cout << endl << "  Digite o Numero: ";
  cin >> n;
  pot = 1;
  bin = 0;
  bin = funcao(n, pot, bin);

  cout << "  " << "Result: " << bin;
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: http://ideone.com/UvF4K2

Answer (score 0):

```
void questao3(int i) {
  if (i > 1) {
    questao3(i / 2);
    if (i) printf("%d", i % 2);
  }
  if ((i == 1) || (!i))
    printf("%d", i);
}
```